# Customized Drop down box

Tags: html, select

I am making this type of drop down as shown in given image.[image]

Can any body tell me how can I get this ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Google custom html dropdown and you will get many options...

Answer (score 2):

You can give it a class and then edit the elements in CSS. [This will teach you the basics](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

So in HTML you give it a class:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>First option</option>
      <option>Second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Now you can add CSS, see the link above :D

Do a quick Google search and you will see loads of help